# Can I insert hyperlinks directly from Wordpad?

Tags: wordpad

**Is it possible to add hyperlinks to a document in Wordpad?**

It's possible to copy hyperlinked text from editors like Microsoft Word, but I don't see a way to insert hyperlinks directly from Wordpad.

[image: Hyperlink pasted from Microsoft Word]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I don't see a way to insert hyperlinks directly from Wordpad

Just type a URL and Wordpad will automatically create a hyperlink for you.

Examples:

[image]

Notes:

- It is not possible to change the link description from within Wordpad.
- A workaround is to save the file as rtf and make the change externally in another editor.

Example:

To change the link description to `this is a link to google` change the second occurrence of `www.google.com` to `this is a link to google` in the rtf.

From:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "www.google.com"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1 www.google.com}}}\f0\fs22\par
}
```

To:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "www.google.com"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf1 this is a link to google}}}\f0\fs22\par
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I've updated my question with a screenshot example.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro That's only possible if you save as rtf and edit the rtf in another program.

Comment: In that case, I'll assume what I'm asking for isn't possible within Wordpad. Can you update your answer to menton this?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Done.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to link to a document you can use File://

e.g. <File://C:\Users\MikeB\Documents\To do list.rtf>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1119776)